# Destructuring assignment of SASS list

Tags: sass, scss-functions

I'm trying to destructuring list of values in SCSS in this way, which works, but I want to get leaner way to do that.

```scss
@function update-list($list) {
  $name: nth($list, 1);
  $dur: nth($list, 2);
  $func: nth($list, 3);

  @debug "list values: #{$name} #{$dur} #{$func}";

  @return $name $dur $func;
}
```

So, I want to replace this part:

```scss
$name: nth($list, 1);
$dur: nth($list, 2);
$func: nth($list, 3);
```

with something like JS do:

```js
[a, b, c] = [10, 20, 30];
```

---

UPD:

I have space-separated list **$list** witch transmitted to function **update-list**.

Also, I've added debug results of this list:

```scss
$list: prop1 prop2 prop3;
@debug "list data: #{type-of($list)} #{length($list)} #{list-separator($list)}";
// DEBUG: list data: list 3 space
$list-upd: update-list($list);
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how you call your function please?

Comment: @Arkellys sure, I've updated question with example, see UPD part. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't destructure like in JS, however you can spread the list params you pass to your function:

```
@function update-list($name, $dur, $func) {
  @debug "list values: #{$name} #{$dur} #{$func}";
  @return $name $dur $func;
}

$list: prop1 prop2 prop3;
$list-upd: update-list($list...);
```

Comment: Perfect! That was exactly I was looking for. 
Thanks a lot.